# ZF2 - ServiceManager injecting into 84 tables... tedious

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I originally made another thread about this a couple of months ago in regards to ZF2 injecting into tables with DI during Beta 1 and figured back then that it wasn't really possible. Now ZF2 has been released as version 2.0.0 and ServiceManager is defaulted to instead of DI I guess I have the same question now I'm refactoring.

I've got 84 tables that need the DbAdapter injecting into them and I'm sure there has to be a better way as I'm replicating myself SO much.

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'accountTable' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $table     = new Model\DbTable\AccountTable($dbAdapter);
                return $table;
            },
            'userTable' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $table     = new Model\DbTable\UserTable($dbAdapter);
                return $table;
            },
            // another 82 tables of the above
        )
    )
}
```

With the EventsManager and ServiceManager I have no idea where I stand in getting my application's instances/resources.

Thanks, Dom

Answer (score 2):

With lots of injections like this, you are best off creating a service manager initalizer, and then implementing an interface like DbAdapterAwareInterface. If you want to see the idea in action, take a look at the EventManagerAwareInterface in the zf2 code base.

Comment: Mmmm, this seems to be hard-coded into the framework. Within Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig.php#configureServiceManager($sm) {
$serviceManager->addInitializer(//stuff)
}

So this listens for the creation of anything using the AwareInterface and injects it there. I guess I have to add my DbAware thing as an initializer

Answer (score 0):

I have written a ZF2 module called [DiWrapper](https://github.com/aimfeld/di-wrapper) which you can use to auto-generate and auto-update this kind of factory code. You will have to provide the `Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter` to DiWrapper as a shared instance. Then you can either use the ServiceManager or DiWrapper to get your table classes.

Answer (score -1):

its really ok. php5.3+ injects only *pointers or "links"